# How i can design database in 3nf

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: schema of database]

I design my database, but I have some problems:

1. how can i check is it in 3 normal form
2. question about `REFERENSES` and `FOREIGN KEY`
   if I choose `ON DELETE CASCADE` for each `FOREIGN KEY`, I can delete some record from table "boat" and I delete reords from tables "team", "jorney", "tickets" and "solded", but how I can delete records from "personal" and "persons" when I delete record from "boat", or it is normal what these records aren't delete from "person" or "personal"
3. actually for (2), maybe I shouldn't set `DELETE ON CASCADE` and write `SET NULL` for each `FOREIGN KEY`

Comment: There's no automatic checks for this. You look at the schema and apply the rules of the normal form in question.

Comment: Ok, what about (2) and (3) how I shoud do: write ON DELETE SET NULL or  ON DELETE CASCADE? and why?

Comment: This is all largely subjective and although they're good questions, they're just a tiny fraction of a larger conversation about database design best practices. This is really far too broad for a Stack Overflow question: Here things should be simple, to the point, and have specific technical solutions. If you have a query that's not producing the correct results, for example, or are having trouble defining a stored procedure, that's more ideal. This line of inquiry could take several hours to fully explain. You should take a course if you're curious.

Comment: A simple [online course](https://www.udemy.com/database-design/) might answer this question and more. If you're missing the fundamentals you need to get that foundation in order to understand any answers you might get.